# How do I selectively update properties on Spring beans with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Given a domain object like:

```
class MyPojo
  get/setA
  get/setB
  get/setC
```

If I use MyPojo as the modelAttribute for a form, that has something like:

```
 <form:form modelAttribute="myPojo" action="nextPage" method="POST">
    <form:input path="a"/>
    <form:input path="b"/>
 </form>
```

And I have a Controller method like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/nextPage"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String theNextPageMethod(@ModelAttribute("myPojo") MyPojo myPojoObj) {
         //call to a service/dao impl are omitted for brevity
         //but the dao impl does:
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(myPojoObj);
}
```

Spring/Hibernate updates myPojoObj with the form input values for properties "a" and "b" but in my case, it's also setting the value of property "c" to null.

Is this the expected behavior?  If so, what is the best practice to preserve any value assigned to property "c"?  Is there an annotation or some other way to only update the properties "a" and "b"?

CLARIFICATION:
Ideally, I'm looking for something to allow for updating "a" and "b" on one page and "b" and "c" on another and keep all the other properties static for each particular request.

Comment: Google this: @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)

Comment: So you would add that annotation to property "c"?

Comment: I think from your description of your requirement it would just be @Column(updatable=false) to property C. This will allow you to insert a value but not any subsequent updates to this column.

Comment: Appreciate the response.  Your solution would technically satisfy the requirement, though you'd have to know apriori which columns to hold static (it would always have to be "c").  So I'm really looking for something like that on the view or controller level (e.g., on one JSP, only update A and B, on another JSP only update B and C).  I can update my question to be more precise.

Comment: Ok - a runtime solution. When you update objects that are persisted you will use some locking mechanism to ensure that someone else hasn't updated your record while you were processing it. The favorite approach is usually an optomistic lock that uses a version field that is either a count or a timestamp that can be compared to the object you present for the update (see @Version). The only reason I mention this is that Hibernate needs to fetch the object in question as a precursor to the update. Because the fetched object is cached it will do no harm for you to fetch it and use its values . . .

Comment: To fill in the nulls in the object you will present for the update. So the columns will be updated, but with the previous values. Be sure not to alter the fetched object as that will prevent the cached copy from being used.

Comment: Ok, so @ OptimisticLock and an @ Version property on MyPojo. Would you set the version and call merge() after that?   If so, the drawback seems to be that you would always need to supply the last version number from the fetched object.  Getting a StaleStateException now and will look into resolving it.

Comment: If you're trying to implement this let me do an answer so I won't run out of room again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you want to store the entity's state? Session, view or db?

Add

@SessionAttributes({"myPojo"})

To your controller

Or use a hidden input field in your view with c's value

Or annotate a controller method with @ModelAttribute and return the entity from the db each request

You can also create a new, smaller POJO just for the form(s) and use Dozer to copy values to/from your real entity, and use dynamic update.

Comment: These would all be good suggestions if MyPojo was small but might not be great down the line since it's a large object with lots of properties.  Regardless, I got it to work with @ SessionAttributes for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try Dynamic-Update Attribute it should solve your problem.

```
@DynamicUpdate
```

Now only changed columns will be update. See also example http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-dynamic-update-attribute-example/

Comment: Hmm - I tried @ DynamicUpdate and @ SelectBeforeUpdate on the MyPojo bean but still don't see the expected behavior.  (The Entity annotation is deprecated in Hibernate 4.)  Will investigate and look at the generated SQL.

Comment: I'm still seeing the UPDATE statement setting all the properties instead of just the dirty ones.  I tried Hibernate 4.1.4, 4.2.8, and 4.3.6 since I saw some logged issues about dynamicUpdate.  I also made sure to use @ Transactional.  Will keep looking.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you use openSession() intead of getCurrentSession() you also need to place object in session with annotation @SelectBeforeUpadete

Comment: I wish that were the issue. I'm Autowiring my SessionFactory and calling sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() in my dao implementation.