# Update one attribute of an Entity with ModelAttribute

Tags: spring, forms, modelattribute

How can I update just one or a few atributes of an Entity with spring form and controller?

Lets say it is User Entity and has id, status, name, address etc...
I want to update just name, and address. But when I try to save ather values is null. ı dont want to show all attributes in form logically ( Id, status )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I selectively update properties on Spring beans with Hibernate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499982/how-do-i-selectively-update-properties-on-spring-beans-with-hibernate)

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden input element to propagate users ID to your view, e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="user-id" value="${editUserForm.id}">
```

Put it in a form - when a form is submitted, users ID will also be submitted with it (remember to add ID to your form model). Then retrieve user from database using this ID, set fields you want to set and update it.

EDIT:

Example:
your model:

```
    @Entity
    public class User{
       private Long id;
       private String name;
       private String surname;
       //getters & setters
    }
```

form you use to edit some of the fields (no surname):

```
public class UserForm{
         private Long id;
         private String name;
         //getters & setters, constructor
    }
```

Controller:

```
 @GetMapping(value="/editUser/{userId}")
    public ModelAndView editUser(@PathVariable Long userId){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("editUser");
    User user = // retrieve user from database using userId
    modelAndView.addObject("editUserForm", new UserForm(user));
    return modelAndView;
    }

    @PostMapping(value="/editUser")
    public ModelAndView postEditUser(@ModelAttribute("editUserForm") UserForm editUserForm){
    User userToEdit = //retrive user from database using editUserForm.getId()
    userToEdit.setName(editUserForm.getName());
    //save user to database
    //redirect
    }
```

Of course logic I presented in controllers should be located in service layer, I just want to give you an idea on what to do.

Comment: id just example. I an have lots of attributes in entities not only id. Some of them needs to be updated some of them not. and sending requestparam for each is very bad solution. I require to way with modelattribute and binding result together.

Comment: My idea is to propagate your id to the view so you can retrieve whole object from database (with all the fields set) and change just those fields that you edit in a form.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: I did not understand, do you mean modelAttribute in form?

Comment: Thanks but I have about 150 entities. I am familiar your solution and if I use this way I have to create at least 150 extra class for entities. I am seeking a way using original entities. Is your way is a standard for big enterprise apps? My app is very big as I said.

Comment: And there is one thing. I use one form to create and update user etc...entities. With this way I can not use same extra class. I have to create one createUser form class, one editUser form class